# Ich bewege mich viel, weil ich gesund bleiben will

Tags: sentence-structure

Can I use here in this sentence "damit" instead of "weil" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write this:

> Ich bewege mich viel, damit ich gesund bleibe.

---

Let's compare these sentences:

> 1. Ich bewege mich viel, weil ich gesund bleiben will.
> 2. Ich bewege mich viel, damit ich gesund bleibe.

In a higher level both sentences express the same, but in a very basic meaning they are different:

In 1 you start with a wish (that came into your mind in the past): "**I want** to stay healthy", and this wish causes you to move a lot. So you move now, to fulfill a wish that was there before you started to move.

In 2 you have a goal for the future: "I want to **stay healthy**", and you move a lot to reach this future/prospective goal.

My English is not the best, but I think you can translate those sentences this way into english:

> 1. I move a lot because I want to stay healthy.
> 2. I move a lot so I can stay healthy.

---

I think, you had this in your mind:

> 3. Ich bewege mich viel, damit ich gesund bleiben will.

But this is wrong. When you say this, you in fact say something like this:

> 3. I move a lot so I wish to stay healthy.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically this sentence would be correct however the sentence would not make sense in most situations.

In both cases (*weil* and *damit*) the sub-ordinate sentence describes the reason why something described in the main sentence is done.

However there is the following difference:

Using *weil* the "activity" in the main sentence is the consequence of the "activity" in the sub-ordinate sentence.

Using *damit* it is the other way round: The "activity" in the sub-ordinate sentence is the consequence of the "activity" in the main sentence.

Let's look at the following two sentences (which differ only on one word):

> Ich fahre langsam, **weil** das andere Auto mich überholt.
>
> I drive slowly because the other car **(already) passes**.
>
> Ich fahre langsam, **damit** das andere Auto mich überholt.
>
> I drive slowly because the other car **shall pass**.

A combination of "*damit*" and "*wollen*" is however possible:

> Die Eltern versprechen ihrem Sohn etwas, **damit** er auf die Reise mitgehen **will**.
>
> The parents promise something because they **want that** their son **wants to** take part in the journey.